# How to make scrollbar like as facebook profile's?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="wrap">
      <div class="left"> photos - friends </div>
      <div class="right"> posts </div>
   </div>
</div>

.container { width: 100%; }
.wrapper { width: 1050px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

I would like to make a layout like as facebook profile's: the div.right will overflow with the scrollbar placing at the right of the screen (not right of the div.right). Is there any way to do that without javascript?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, when the right overflows, the position of the scrollbar is on the right side of the screen. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tszhong0411/pen/mdXvdZy)

Comment: Sorry my English is not good. I mean I'd like the scrollbar of the div.right at the right edge of the screen, not at the right edge of the div.right.

Comment: The link in my previous comment already shows the scrollbar at the right edge of the screen.

Comment: https://codepen.io/ntav2095/pen/zYRexdb I have a layout like this. I want the div.right's scrollbar to be at the right edge of the screen, not the wrap or div.right. :)

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change the position of the scrollbar. But why did you limit the height of the container? I think there are other ways to solve it.

Comment: I want to make it like facebook profile page. You can visit there to take a look at it. I have a way to do archive it but the code looks not good. I'd like to find a another cleaner way. Thanks a lot for helping me. :)

Answer (score 0):

When creating custom scroll bar you don't need any diva
Just add this to your css

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer gotten from  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

Comment: Thanks! But I meant I want to have the scrollbar position at the right of the screen, for away its div, not modifying its color or size. I just know how to change position of the scrollbar to the right, bottom, left, top of its div, but I'd like to place it at the right of the screen. :)